# table constraints - primary keys in mysql

Tags: mysql, constraints, primary-key

I have a following table :

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `a1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `a2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`a1`,`a2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Here When I assign values,

```
insert into a values(1,2);
```

After that if I give :

```
insert into a values(1,20);
insert into a values(10,2);
```

Here I've declared a1 and a2 as primary key that means it's `unique` and `not null` by default. But it accepts duplicates (for a1 - (1,2) and (1,20)) as given above. It shouldn't right? It gives error only when I give :

```
insert into a values(1,2);

ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1-2' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Whereas I cannot leave a column (not a combination of columns) as null. It executes primary key like pairs but `not null` in individual columns. Why that happens?? Can anyone explain me???

Comment: A primary key is a unique key , you have defined it over 2 columns , a duplicate error occurs when both column values exist in the table and you try to insert the same 2 values again.

Comment: Refer to documentation & justify why pairs being unique would imply individual columns being unique. (It doesn't.) Don't just make a claim with "doens't it'--we can't point out your reasoning errors if you don't give your reasoning. Also this is a faq.

Answer (score 5):

when you declare composite primary keys (a1 and a2 together), they need to be unique together. which means you cannot insert `(1,2)` more then once.

if you need a1 and a2 will be unique on their own, you need to create unique index on each column.

```
ALTER TABLE a
  ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE KEY(a2);


ALTER TABLE a
  ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name2 UNIQUE KEY(a1);
```

the role of the primary key is to to define unicity for each table row.

Comment: @Strawberry I edited my answer. I am little bit distracted. sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are using composite keys. And it's functionality is that only. When you declared your primary key automatically `not null` constraint gets added to both the fields and that's why it acts in individual columns and primary key's uniqueness is a combination of both the fields here